# I want to get output with one command line in private host through bastion server using one key pair

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, netcat

I want to get output with one command line in private host through bastion server using **one key pair**.
Referencely, bastion server and private host share one key pair and key pair is in my local macbook.

How can I get an output (ex. ls) on my local macbook with one command line?

mac > bastion > private ip host (I want to output of ls command)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQxwa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by using a [ProxyJump](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump) in your `.ssh/config`, for example:

```
Host private.host
  ProxyJump <user>@bastion.host
```

This will allow you to do:

```
$ ssh private.host ls /
```

Or without modifying your config file you could use something like:

```
$ ssh -J bastion.host private.host ls /
```