# How can I create a ssh tunnel on MacOS?

Tags: macos, ssh, putty, tunnel

in my work we are using an ssh authentication for our server. In the past I was working on windows, now I had to switch to MacOS.
Anyway, as I was using PuTTY it wasn't a problem to connect to the host address and add an destination via a tunnel.
In the terminal of MacOS I managed to connect to the host address. But I'm absolutely clueless how to connect to the other destination via a tunnel. Actually I just want to reach the same effect as on Windows with PuTTY: a 'normal' ssh connection to the host and another connection to another destination via a tunnel.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51534450/1135424

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up a Terminal, you'll discover that macOS is ‘just another unix’ underneath (I omit a mass of irrelevant detail here).  Thus you can use the same instructions on macOS that you'll find online for Linux, or any other unix.

The [instructions at ssh.com](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) seem reasonable, but anything you google will be fine.